# Zenity buttons not working

Tags: bash, debian, exit-status, dialog, zenity

So i can't figured out why my cancel button is not working on the confirmation delete zenity box... Can you please explain me ?

```
directory=$(zenity --entry \
    --text "Enter a path" \
    --title "Delete"\
    --ok-label "Done" )
    ret=$?

    if ((ret==0));then

        if [ -z "$directory" ];then #Check if user entered a path or not.
            directory=$(pwd)    #If not take the actual path.
        fi
        if [ -d "$directory" ];then #Check if entered path exist.
            Spath=$(zenity --file-selection --filename="$directory/" --title "File Browser")
            #Change the directory otherwise will not delete the wanted              file.           
            cd $directory
        fi
        if (($?==0));then
            #Check if the user really want to delete this file.
            zenity --question --icon-name "edit-delete" --title "Confirmation" --text "Are you sure you want to delete this file?"

            #Getting only the file name from the path
            Sfile=$(basename "$Spath")
            echo $?
            clear $?
```

The problem is on this section , when pressing cancel , it follow the 'ok' button path.

```
            if (($?==0));then
                rm -f "$Sfile"  #Delete the file.
            elif (($?==1));then
                echo $?
                zenity --error --title "Info" --text "No file was deleted"
            fi      
        fi
        
    else
        #If not existing show error message.
        zenity --error --title "Error" --text "The path you entered does not exist" 
    fi
```

Comment: Be aware that `$?` is the exit status of the most recent command, including `if`: `if false; then true; fi; echo $?`. It's really hard to tell with the posted code what "most recent command" you're testing. You need to save the $? value more often than you currently are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `$?` means the return code of the **very last** command run.

So if you refer to `$?` after running `Sfile=$(basename "$Spath")`, then `$?` represents the status of the `basename` command. Next references to `$?` refer to next commands.

If you want to test return code of the `zenity` command, then you should set `ret=$?` **right after** call to `zenity` (similarly as you already did at the beginning of the file) and then check the value of `$ret` and not `$?`.